# Kotlin Gradle Build Error & Using Kotlin Lib as Maven dependency in spring boot, what is the trick?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I have a really cool kotlin/gradle lib that i want to use in a spring boot micro service developed in Java. Its is a market data API for Polygon [Client JVM GitHub](https://github.com/polygon-io/client-jvm)

I am bran new to Kotlin, have made my around in this project, they have some Sample Java Usage code that runs in my IDE, I am now trying to import this project into a Maven spring boot service and in the gradle.build of the project there is a maven publish plugin being referenced, I can't find the client lib in any public maven repo so I am trying to build it locally, it works in my Intelij IDE but command line get this error

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
```

My other key question is, assuming I can get the artifact to build and publish it into my local ~/.m2 repository is it possible for me in spring boot java to import it like i would for any other maven lib and instantiate/invoke class methods developed in Kotlin while I am in in Java/Spring boot or is the process not that easy?

This is the build.gradle of the client lib as you can see it does reference the maven publish plugin, to get this to publish is the command gradle publish? Of course I would have to get it to build first.

```
plugins {
`java-library`
`maven-publish`
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10"
kotlin("kapt") version "1.6.10"
```

}

Comment: The "Deprecated Gradle features" bit should just be a warning (i.e., it won't prevent the build from succeeding, but the build will probably break when updating to Gradle 9+). As for using the published artifact in another project, if it's Maven-based then it should look in the local repository by default, and if it's Gradle-based then you just have to add `mavenLocal()` to your repositories.

Comment: With the [`maven-publish`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks) plugin, publishing to the local Maven repository *should* be as easy as executing the `publishToMavenLocal` task.